# Python 3 Tkinter Splashscreen

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I've been wanting to add an image displayed as a Splash Screen before the main program shows up, but I can't get it to work.

I want the image to be centered in the monitor and ONLY show the image and nothing else.

My code is this:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width*0.8, height*0.8, width*0.1, 
height*0.1))
image_file = "Flexbase.png"
image = tk.PhotoImage(file=image_file)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=height*0.8, width=width*0.8, bg="brown")
canvas.create_image(width*0.8/2, height*0.8/2, image=image)
canvas.pack()
root.after(5000, root.destroy)
root.mainloop()
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone explain to me how displaying an image works?

P.S.: If this information will help, the image itself is 640x160 and doesn't have anything transparent.

Comment: So what exactly goes wrong when you run this?  I assume it's something to do with the fact that `PhotoImage` doesn't support PNG, you need to use the PIL/Pillow library's `ImageTk` to load most common image file formats.

Comment: @jasonharper, the problem is.. I run the program, the window with the image gets displayed in the center but there's red colour all around it. I want only the image to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: I want the image to be centered in the monitor and ONLY show the image and nothing else.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenheight()

image_file = "Flexbase.png"
image = tk.PhotoImage(file=image_file)
```

---

- Window `width` and `height` should be equal to the `image` size

  ```
  x = int((width / 2) - (image.width() / 2))
  y = int((height / 2) - (image.height() / 2))
  geometry = '{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(image.width(), image.height(), x, y)

  root.geometry(geometry)
  ```
- **No**, further math on `canvas` size, the `canvas` expands by default.

  ```
  canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
  ```
- Place the `image` at **top/left**  using `anchor`**top/left**

  ```
  canvas.create_image(0,0, image=image, anchor='nw')
  ```

---

```
canvas.pack()

root.after(3000, root.destroy)
root.mainloop()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***

Comment: With this solution, half of the image is being displayed and then the rest of it is filled with white colour.

Comment: Yes I did. I even copy-pasted it. I'm running Python version 3.7 btw

Comment: @KitsuneMakoto: Edit your Question and show at least the `canvas ...` code lines. `.create_image(...` places a `image` centered at the given coordinate, here `0, 0`. To verify if the `canvas` are **expanded** use `tk.Canvas(..., bg="brown")`. The whole window should be `'brown'`.

Answer (score 0):

I bring the image with this code:

```
arrow = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("go-next.png"))
```

As a note, you can also remove the title bar with this

```
root.wm_attributes('-type', 'splash')
```

It makes the splash screen look much better