# TKinter Splashscreen not working for GUI based application for Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to build a GUI based code, where there will be a splashcreen, a wait for 5 seconds and then the main GUI should show up. I am using Python 3.6. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, PhotoImage, Canvas, Label 
from time import sleep 


root = Tk() 
root.overrideredirect(True)

width = root.winfo_screenwidth() 
height = root.winfo_screenheight() 

image_file = 'splash_fig.png'
splashImage = PhotoImage(file = image_file)
w = splashImage.width() 
h = splashImage.height() 

y = int((height - h) / 2) 
x = int((width - w) / 2) 

root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w,h,x,y))

canvas = Canvas(root,height = h, width = w, bg = "brown")
canvas.create_image(0,0,image = splashImage, anchor='nw') 
canvas.pack() 

root.after(5000, root.destroy) 
root.mainloop() 


root = Tk() 
my_label = Label(root, text="Something something")
my_label.pack() 
root.mainloop()
```

What is happening is that the splashscreen does not show up, but the second GUI does! Where is the exact problem here! My question is an extension to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54367521/python-3-tkinter-splashscreen), where I have closely followed the solution proposed

Comment: Your code work just fine for me. Are you sure your splashscreen didnt show up? Try raise the window to the top by `root.attributes("-topmost", True)`.

Comment: Ok. I moved the code to Linux and found that the code works. I was running it in Python 3.6+ on Mac OSX. Appears to be a glitch on MacOS. How can I communicate this to the community?